# An Unknown feature in C# Maybe Just For Me

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)

What is it? Is it useful? Where?

```
??
```

Comment: Please edit this question to be a little clearer.  Are you askng about the "?" operator or the "??" operator here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It work this way;

```
Object a = otherObject ?? "otherObject is null";
```

It means `otherObject` will be assigned to "a" if it is not null. If it is null the object at right will be assigned to "a".

Its useful for me when I wanna set default values;

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Object b;
    public MyClass(Object a)
    {
        b = a ?? "Deafult Value";
    }
}
```

Official documentation can also be found here; [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: **Hey bro,Can you explain more?**

Comment: otherObject will be assigned to a if it is not null. If it is null the object at right will be assigned to a. Is it now clear bro?

Comment: Yeah,thanks so much.**muchas grasias** :) :*

Comment: Youre welcome, or **de nada**!

Answer (score 8):

This is the null-coalescing operator and allows you to set a default value if the object is null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
object o = someObject ?? anotherObject;
```

is the same

```
object o;
if(someObject == null)
  o = anotherObject;
else
  o = someObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

*The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for a nullable value types as well as reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

```
    // Assign i to return value of method, unless
    // return value is null, in which case assign
    // default value of int to i.
    int i = GetNullableInt() ?? default(int);
```

*

Maybe you can use it to simplify some repetitive code pieces.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the null coalescing operator ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx ).

You can use it to return the right hand side of it, if the left hand side is null; otherwise, it will return left hand side.

For example, you can use it to simplify this (in an ASP.NET application):

```
public string SessionStore
{
    get 
    { 
        if( Session["MyData"] == null )
        {
            return "default value";
        }

        return (string)(Session["MyData"]);
    }
    set { Session["MyData"] = value; }
}
```

Into this :

```
public string SessionStore
{
    get { return (string)(Session["MyData"]) ?? "default value"; }
    set { Session["MyData"] = value; }
}
```